# Partition string into chunks

Tags: string-manipulation

This seems like it should be trivial, but how do I partition a string into length `n` substrings? I can of course write something like

```
chunk[s_, n_] := StringJoin[#] & /@ Partition[Characters[s], n]
```

so that `chunk["ABCDEF",2]` -> `{"AB","CD","EF"}` but this appears unnecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  This is a good question, as there doesn't seem to be a direct built-in way (I bumped into this before).  Please consider filling out the name field in your profile, so it will show as something easier to remember than 'user1268'

Comment: [Link to MathGroup version](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/eEOdY75K2Ds/discussion).

Comment: Note `StringJoin[#] &` is the same as just `StringJoin`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
StringCases["ABCDEFGHIJK", LetterCharacter ~~ LetterCharacter]
```

> `{"AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ"}`

or for more general cases (i.e. not just for letters, but any characters, and for any partition size):

```
stringPartition1[s_String, n_Integer] := StringCases[s, StringExpression @@ Table[_, {n}]];
```

It is more elegant though to use `Repeated` (thanks rcollyer):

```
stringPartition2[s_String, n_Integer] := StringCases[s, Repeated[_, {n}]];

stringPartition2["longteststring", 4]
```

> `{"long", "test", "stri"}`

Comment: Instead of `Table[_,{n}]`, I'd consider using [`Repeated[_, {n}]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7122499/198315), instead.

Comment: Thanks @rcollyer, I felt I missed something, but it was too late. Incorporated now.

Answer (score 20):

Here is the regular-expression way:

```
chunk[s_, n_] := 
 StringCases[s, RegularExpression[".{1," <> ToString[n] <> "}"]]

chunk["Hello this is a test string", 2]
```

> `{"He", "ll", "o ", "th", "is", " i", "s ", "a ", "te", "st", " s", "tr", "in", "g"}`

```
chunk["Hello this is a test string", 4]
```

> `{"Hell", "o th", "is i", "s a ", "test", " str", "ing"}`

Note that the last substrings didn't fit the chunk size but were still included.

If you don't want to include them, change the regular expression from `".{1," <> ToString[n] <> "}"` to `".{" <> ToString[n] <> "}"`.

Answer (score 15):

Another possibility:

```
StringTake[#, 
   Partition[Range@StringLength@#, 2, 2, 1, {}]] &@"abcdefghi"
```

giving

```
(*  {"ab", "cd", "ef", "gh", "i"} *)
```

Answer (score 12):

Not completely original, but very compact.

```
chunk[s_, n_] := StringJoin@@@Partition[Characters[s], n, n, 1, {}]
```

---

**Update for V10.1**

This new function is exactly for that:

```
StringPartition["ABCDEF",2]
```

> `{"AB", "CD", "EF"}`

Answer (score 8):

This will give better performance (3 times faster in my test, partitioning into length-two strings) than your original code:

```
chunk[s_, n_] := FromCharacterCode@Partition[ToCharacterCode[s], n]
```

The reason is that the first few steps of the computation are done with packed arrays.

It will still be slower than the regex-based approaches (István's and Jens's), on my machine by a factor of 2.

The `StringTake` approach is much slower than all the others in my machine.

#### Benchmarks

Function definitions:

```
(* original *)
chunk1[s_, n_] := StringJoin[#] & /@ Partition[Characters[s], n]

(* István *)
chunk2[s_, n_] := StringCases[s, Repeated[_, {n}]]

(* Jens *)
chunk3[s_, n_] := StringCases[s, RegularExpression[".{1," <> ToString[n] <> "}"]]

(* TomD *)
chunk4 = StringTake[#, Partition[Range@StringLength@#, #2, #2, 1, {}]] &;

(* mine *)
chunk5[s_, n_] := FromCharacterCode@Partition[ToCharacterCode[s], n]

text = ExampleData[{"Text", "Hamlet"}];
testString = StringJoin[ConstantArray[text, 20]];

StringLength[testString] (* 3438740 *)
```

Timings:

```
(* original *)
In[10]:= Timing[chunk1[testString, 2];]
         Timing[chunk1[testString, 100];]

Out[10]= {5.968, Null}
Out[11]= {1.703, Null}

(* István - fastest *)
In[12]:= Timing[chunk2[testString, 2];]
         Timing[chunk2[testString, 100];]

Out[12]={1.25, Null}
Out[13]={0.11, Null}

(* Jens - fastest *)
In[14]:= Timing[chunk3[testString, 2];]
         Timing[chunk3[testString, 100];]

Out[14]= {1.313, Null}
Out[15]= {0.125, Null}

(* TomD *)
In[16]:= Timing[chunk4[testString, 2];]
         Timing[chunk4[testString, 100];]

(* More than a few minutes. Didn't wait for it to finish ... *)

(* mine *)
In[18]:= Timing[chunk5[testString, 2];]
         Timing[chunk5[testString, 100];]

Out[18]= {2.25, Null}
Out[19]= {0.266, Null}
```

Conclusion: use regex-based methods.  The built-in string patterns also use a regex library internally, I believe, but they are easier to construct programmatically because they are represented as expressions.

Comment: Scrollbar ate your timing results... First I thought it was so lightning fast you did not bother to write it out in numbers :)

Comment: Thanks, Szabolcs, and everyone who answered. As ever, more than one way to skin a cat with Mathematica. I'm a bit surprised that there isn't a `StringPartition` function taking the same arguments as `Partition` as a built-in, analogous to `StringTake` vs. `Take`.

Comment: +1, I did not know about that behavior of `ToCharacterCode` and `FromCharacterCode`. It makes splitting a string into individual characters a lot simpler.

Comment: Your code can be further sped up by using ``Developer`PartitionMap`` to apply `FromCharacterCode` to each term in the list. This does not unpack the list. The speed up is marginal, though, on my machine `1.25793 -> 1.12617` and `0.135588 -> 0.095252`. So, still not a contender for the fastest method.

Comment: @rcollyer Good point!  I never used ``Developer`PartitionMap`` before. (I've seen it in the docs, but I didn't realize its significance: not unpacking.)

Comment: I really would like to see the internals of the ``Developer` `` package. Mostly to see how one goes about avoiding unpacking. That, and I'd like a variant of that that works with ``Internal`PartitionRagged``.

Comment: @rcollyer It should be possible to write something like `PartitionMap` using LibraryLink.  I have to admit though I never manipulated general expressions with it (only numerical tensors).  The idea would be not to map first, evaluate later (i.e. `Sqrt /@ {4,5}` -> `{Sqrt[4], Sqrt[5]} -> {2, Sqrt[5]}), but evaluate first, then insert into the (preallocated) array.

Comment: I had not thought of using `LibraryLink` to do that sort of processing ...

Comment: @rcollyer Actually, what I described could be implemented efficiently in Mathematica, I think,  The difficulty would be to keep the result array packed as well.  So I started experimenting, and found something I don't really understand: if `Map` maps first, and leaves the result to be evaluated later, as my example was meant to demostrate above, then why is ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[Sqrt /@ N@Range[100]] === True``?

Comment: @rcollyer I get the same behaviour with ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[Identity /@ N@Range[100]]``---no unpacking.  But I can't manage to create a function myself that I could use in place of `Identity` or `Sqrt` in this example and it would not unpack.  Does `Map` simply special case all these?  I understand they would special-case `Sqrt`, but why `Identity`?

Comment: It is length based. Try, using `Range[50]` instead.

Comment: @rcollyer I solved the 'mystery': it was auto-compilation.  It avoids unpacking only if the list is above the auto-compilation length.

Comment: @rcollyer Your comment was not yet there when I started writing mine, but it appeared when I finished :-)

Answer (score 6):

I wanted a solution using `StringSplit[]`

```
chunk[s_, n_] := StringSplit[s, RegularExpression["(.{" <> ToString@n <> "})"] -> "$1"]
                                                                     ~ DeleteCases ~ ""
```

Comment: Cleaner, IMO: `StringSplit[s, x : Repeated[_, {n}] :> x][[;; ;; 2]]`.  I don't see an advantage over `StringCases` however.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No advantage. I just wanted a way to use `StringSplit[]` as said. But I'm too old to remember _why_ I wanted that.

Answer (score 4):

*Historical note:*

```
WolframLanguageData["StringPartition"
 , {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

> {10.1, DateObject[{2015, 3, 30}, "Day", "Gregorian", 5.]}

---

The command supports `UpTo` as well as *offset* specs, similar to `Partition`.

```
str = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

StringPartition[str, UpTo[2]]
```

> {"AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "K"}

```
StringPartition[str, 2, 1]
```

> {"AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH", "HI", "IJ", "JK"}

```
StringPartition[str, UpTo[7]]
```

> {"ABCDEFG", "HIJK"}

Answer (score 4):

Using `SequenceCases` (new in 10.1)

```
str = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
```

```
SequenceCases[Characters[str], x : {Repeated[_, {2}]} :> StringJoin[x]]
```

> {"AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ"}

```
SequenceCases[Characters[str], x : {Repeated[_, {1, 2}]} :> StringJoin[x]]
```

> {"AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ", "K"}

```
SequenceCases[Characters[str], x : {Repeated[_, {1, 7}]} :> StringJoin[x]]
```

> {"ABCDEFG", "HIJK"}

```
SequenceCases[
 Characters[str], 
 x : {Repeated[_, {2}]} :> StringJoin[x], 
 Overlaps -> True]
```

> {"AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH", "HI", "IJ", "JK"}

```
SequenceCases[
 Characters[str], 
 x : {Repeated[_, {1, 2}]} :> StringJoin[x], 
 Overlaps -> True]
```

> {"AB", "BC", "CD", "DE", "EF", "FG", "GH", "HI", "IJ", "JK", "K"}

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
```

---

Using `MovingMap`:

```
MovingMap["" <> # &, Characters[str], 1][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]
```

> `{"AB", "CD", "EF", "GH", "IJ"}`