# Split string into sub-strings of length n

Tags: programming, string-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Partition string into chunks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/partition-string-into-chunks)

How can I split a string into sub strings of length n?  For example I have a string

```
"ABCDEabcde1234"
```

I would like to split it into

```
{"AB", "CD", "Ea", "bc", "de", "12", "34"}
```

How can I achieve this?  I have looked at the `StringSplit[]` documentation but that seems like it only works for splitting a string by character, not length.

Comment: I see a multitude of answers coming! Perfect for non-experts.

Comment: @IstvánZachar it may very well give experts a run for their money, too. As there are a _lot_ of choices.

Comment: As a first hint: look up `Partition[]` and `Characters[]`.

Comment: I will restrain myself for an hour...

Comment: You can do `StringCases[..., _~~_]`, for instance

Comment: [Related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5644/106) (Partition string into chunks)

Comment: @Tom, a dupe, actually. :) (Thanks.)

Comment: End of party... Sad that my memory is so short.

Answer (score 8):

I think @OleksandrR once suggested to me in chat this solution

```
stringPartition[s_, n_]:=StringCases[s, Repeated[_, n]]
```

The key is that the option `Overlaps` defaults to `False`. If you want to be on the safe side you can add it explicitly

If you want the last part to be removed if it doesn't have `n` elements, you could use `Repeated[_, {n}]` instead.

Comment: The regex equivalent: `StringCases[str, RegularExpression[".{1," <> ToString[k] <> "}"]]`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
splitstring[String : str_, n_] := StringJoin @@@ Partition[Characters[str], n, n, 1, {}]

In[116]:= splitstring["ABCDEabcde1234", 2]

Out[116]= {"AB", "CD", "Ea", "bc", "de", "12", "34"}
```

As J.M. notes below:

```
splitstring[String : str_, n_] := StringJoin @@@ Partition[Characters[str], n]
```

works just as well, but will drop characters at the end if your string length isn't a multiple of `n`.

So choose based on your need.

Comment: ...the non-expert answer.

Comment: `StringJoin @@@ Partition[Characters[str], n]` works just as well.

Comment: @J.M., only if you have a multiple of the partition size. Right? Your way drops characters at the end in some instances.

Comment: @J.M. If the string was a character longer, it would be lost with a partition size of two. `splitstring["ABCDEabcde12345", 2]` outputs `{"AB", "CD", "Ea", "bc", "de", "12", "34"}`.

Comment: True. I suppose that depends on whether the length of OP's strings would always be commensurate with the partition length...

Comment: With v10.3, one can use `UpTo`: `StringJoin @@@ Partition[Characters[str], UpTo[n]]`.