# Finding all sublists or substrings of a given list/string

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, combinatorics

Given a list or string, how do I get a list of all (contiguous) sublists/substrings? The order is not important.

Example for lists:

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
sublists[list]
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Example for strings:

```
string = "abc";
substrings[string]
(* {"", "", "", "", "a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc"} *)
```

Comment: related [16556](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16556/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Interesting, thanks. I searched for loads of things with "substrings", "subsequences" and "sublists", but for some reason that one didn't turn up. I might check out the `Table` approach from that answer though, and include it here, too.

Comment: Yes, search engine is not the best. I was looking for a duplicates/related with "is:answer isaccepted:yes ReplaceList" since `ReplaceList` is not commonly used and probably best suited for this kind of job. So yes, search works if you know the answer :P

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8740525/695132), which doesn't answer your question but it's related and interesting.  The reason why I found that answer very interesting is that the performance is very good, in fact the best of all non-compiled solutions.  That's counterintuitive as pattern matching is typically slow.

Comment: @Kuba Since the search engine could use improvement the best policy is, IMHO, to add **related** links just as you did, which makes the **Linked** bar to the right very useful.

Comment: Also related: [(3443)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3443/121), [(5644)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5644/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[TMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) applies to both of these problems. Below I present an overview of various approaches I've come across, followed by timing data obtained in 10.4 on Windows 10 (the timing code is available as well, so you can easily rerun the tests on your own machine if you have a different setup). Which solution is best for you depends both on the problem size as well as which ordering of the sublists or substrings you're looking for.

One note up front: several implementations use the 10.0 function `Catenate`. If you're using an older version, this can be replaced with `Join @@` which is a bit slower but probably won't change the overall performance ordering of the solutions.

### Sublists

1. These can be generated very concisely with `ReplaceList` and an appropriate pattern.

   ```
   sublists1[list_List] := ReplaceList[list, {___, sub___, ___}:>{sub}]
   ```

   To omit empty sublists, simply replace `sub___` by `sub__`.
2. Alternatively, just generate them explicitly from start and end indices, using `Table`. You'll need to `Catenate` the result though, or you'll get the sublists grouped by starting index:

   ```
   sublists2[list_List] := Catenate @ Table[
     list[[i ;; j]], 
     {i, Length@list + 1}, 
     {j, i-1, Length@list}
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty sublists, let `j` start from `i` instead of `i-1`.
3. As of 10.1 there is `SequenceCases` whose `Overlaps` option can be used to get all the sublists:

   ```
   sublists3[list_List] := SequenceCases[list, {___}, Overlaps -> All]
   ```

   To omit empty sublists, use `{__}` instead of `{___}`. [Credits for this approach go to RunnyKine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111771/2305).
4. Instead of using `Table` we can also construct the index pairs of each sublist from `Subsets`. However, this only gives one instance of the empty list, so we'll need to add the others manually:

   ```
   sublists4[list_List] := With[{len = Length@list},
     Join[
       ConstantArray[{}, len], 
       Take[list, #] & /@ Subsets[Range@len, 2]
     ]
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty sublists, ditch `Join` and `ConstantArray` and replace `2` with `{1,2}`. [Credits for this approach go to Kuba.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72618/2305)
5. As of 10.4 there's even a built-in for this task, but for some reason it also returns only one copy of the empty list:

   ```
   sublists5[list_List] := ConstantArray[{}, Length@list]~Join~Subsequences[list]
   ```

   To omit empty sublists, ditch `Join` and `ConstantArray` and give `Subsequences` an *nspec* of `{1,Infinity}`.
6. You can also collect the results of using `Partition` with overlaps and all possible sublist lengths:

   ```
   sublists6[list_List] := Catenate @ Table[
     Partition[list, n, 1], 
     {n, 0, Length@list}
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty sublists, simply remove the `0,`.

When performance is not a concern, the most important distinguishing feature of these is the order of the returned sublists:

```
list = {1, 2, 3};
sublists1@list (* ReplaceList *)
sublists2@list (* Table *)
sublists3@list (* SequenceCases *)
sublists4@list (* Subsets *)
sublists5@list (* Subsequences *)
sublists6@list (* Partition *)

(* {{}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}, {2}, {2, 3}, {}, {3}, {}} *)
(* {{}, {1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {}, {2}, {2, 3}, {}, {3}, {}} *)
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}, {}, {2, 3}, {2}, {}, {3}, {}, {}} *)
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}} *)
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Things to note: `ReplaceList` orders them by starting index, followed by length. `SequenceCases` does the same but takes length from longest to shortest. `Subsequences` and `Partitions` have them in order of increasing length first. Somewhat weirdly `Subset` first has the length-0 and length-1 lists, and then lists the remaining ones in the same order as `ReplaceList`. Note that while the `Table` approach here uses the same ordering as `ReplaceList` this one is most easily adapted to different ordering by changing the limits and order of the iterators.

Finally, timing results. Most notably, `SequenceCases` is unusably slow for larger lists (so I've omitted it from the longer timing results), but `Subsequences` also gets much slower than rolling your own implementation:

```
list = RandomInteger[5, 100];
RepeatedTiming[sublists1[list];] (*ReplaceList*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists2[list];] (*Table*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists3[list];] (*SequenceCases*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists4[list];] (*Subsets*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists5[list];] (*Subsequences*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists6[list];] (*Partition*)
(*
    {0.00513, Null}
    {0.00452, Null}
    {0.018, Null}    <-- nope
    {0.00378, Null}
    {0.00208, Null}
    {0.00187, Null}
*)
```

```
list = RandomInteger[5, 1000];
RepeatedTiming[sublists1[list];] (*ReplaceList*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists2[list];] (*Table*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists4[list];] (*Subsets*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists5[list];] (*Subsequences*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists6[list];] (*Partition*)
(*
  {2.81, Null}
  {1.2, Null}
  {1.2, Null}
  {2.3, Null}
  {2.0, Null}
*)
```

```
list = RandomInteger[5, 1200];
RepeatedTiming[sublists1[list];] (*ReplaceList*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists2[list];] (*Table*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists4[list];] (*Subsets*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists5[list];] (*Subsequences*)
RepeatedTiming[sublists6[list];] (*Partition*)
(*
  {4.6, Null}
  {2.0, Null}
  {2.0, Null}
  {5.1, Null}
  {6.0, Null}
*)
```

In summary, the `Table` solution is the overall winner in terms of flexibility and performance, but it's good to have some other options for a terse quick-and-dirty solution when you can afford to prioritise readability.

### Substrings

There are several more possibilities for strings (which usually map to an approach above), because you can usually either use specific string functions or convert the string to a list of characters to reduce it to one of the above implementations. (And unfortunately, it's not always the case that the string-based solution is faster.)

1. Adapt the above `ReplaceList` approach by applying `Characters` to the string first, and then replace `{sub}` by `StringJoin[sub]`:

   ```
   substrings1[string_String] := ReplaceList[
     Characters @ string, 
     {___, sub___, ___} :> StringJoin[sub]
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, use `sub__`.
2. Write a similar version with `StringReplaceList` and `StringExpression` for pattern. The catch is to anchor the `StringExpression`, otherwise you'll get horrible amounts of duplicates.

   ```
   substrings2[string_String] := StringReplaceList[
     string, 
     StartOfString ~~ ___ ~~ sub___ ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfString :> sub
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, use `sub__`.
3. The `StringReplaceList` version can be written more compactly with a `RegularExpression`:

   ```
   substrings3[string_String] := StringReplaceList[
     string, 
     RegularExpression["^.*(.*).*$"] :> "$1"
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, use the regex `"^.*(.+).*$"`.
4. Adapt the above `Table` approach, similar to 1, by obtaining the characters first:

   ```
   substrings4[string_String] := Module[{chars = Characters@string},
     Join @@ Table[
       StringJoin @@ chars[[i ;; j]],
       {i, Length@chars + 1},
       {j, i - 1, Length@chars}
     ]
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, let `j` start from `i`.
5. Write a similar version which uses string manipulation functions:

   ```
   substrings5[string_String] :=
    Join @@ Table[
      StringTake[string, {i, j}],
      {i, StringLength@string + 1},
      {j, i - 1, StringLength@string}
    ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, let `j` start from `i`.
6. Adapt the above `SequenceCases` approach using `StringCases`.

   ```
   substrings6[string_String] := StringCases[string, ___, Overlaps -> All]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, use `__`. [Credits for this approach go to SquareOne.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72630/2305)
7. Adapt Kuba's `Subsets` solution:

   ```
   substrings7[string_String] := With[{len = StringLength@string},
     Join[
       ConstantArray["", len], 
       StringTake[string, #] & /@ Subsets[Range@len, 2]
     ]
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, ditch `Join` and `ConstantArray` and replace `2` with `{1,2}`.
8. Adapt the `Partition` solution using `StringPartition`, which was added in 10.1 and updated in 10.4:

   ```
   substrings8[string_String] := Catenate@Table[
     StringPartition[string, n, 1], 
     {n, 0, StringLength@string}
   ]
   ```

   To omit empty strings, remove the `0,`.

There is no string pendant to `Subsequences` at this point.

Let's look at the order of the results:

```
string = "abc";
substrings1[string](*ReplaceList*)
substrings2[string](*StringReplaceList + StringPattern*)
substrings3[string](*StringReplaceList + RegularExpression*)
substrings4[string](*Table + Characters*)
substrings5[string](*Table + StringTake*)
substrings6[string](*StringCases*)
substrings7[string](*Subsets*)
substrings8[string](*StringPartition*)
(*
  {"", "a", "ab", "abc", "", "b", "bc", "", "c", ""}
  {"", "c", "", "bc", "b", "", "abc", "ab", "a", ""}
  {"", "c", "", "bc", "b", "", "abc", "ab", "a", ""}
  {"", "a", "ab", "abc", "", "b", "bc", "", "c", ""}
  {"", "a", "ab", "abc", "", "b", "bc", "", "c", ""}
  {"abc", "ab", "a", "", "bc", "b", "", "c", "", ""}
  {"", "", "", "", "a", "b", "c", "ab", "abc", "bc"}
  {"", "", "", "", "a", "b", "c", "ab", "bc", "abc"}
*)
```

Interestingly, `StringReplaceList` yields the opposite order from `ReplaceList` (which I believe is due to greedy matching of the prefix), which itself orders them by starting index first, length second. `StringCases`, like `SubsequenceCases` does the same but with decreasing length. `Subsets` still has its funny order of index pairs and the `StringPartition` solution sorts them by length. Again, remember that the `Table` approaches can easily be adapted to yield almost any order you want.

As for performance, and it turns out that the `StringReplaceList` versions are *much* slower than the other three. Timing them for a 100-character string:

```
string = StringJoin @ ConstantArray["a", 100];
Timing[substrings1[string];](*ReplaceList*)
Timing[substrings2[string];](*StringReplaceList + StringPattern*)
Timing[substrings3[string];](*StringReplaceList + RegularExpression*)
Timing[substrings4[string];](*Table + Characters*)
Timing[substrings5[string];](*Table + StringTake*)
Timing[substrings6[string];](*StringCases*)
Timing[substrings7[string];](*Subsets*)
Timing[substrings8[string];](*StringPartition*)
(*
    {0., Null}
    {3.84375, Null}
    {5.28125, Null}
    {0.015625, Null}
    {0., Null}
    {0.015625, Null}
    {0., Null}
    {0., Null}
*)
```

Comparing the others, we find that the string-based `Table` and `Subsets` approaches easily outperform the others on large inputs:

```
string = StringJoin @ ConstantArray["a", 100];
RepeatedTiming[substrings1[string];](*ReplaceList*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings4[string];](*Table + Characters*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings5[string];](*Table + StringTake*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings6[string];](*StringCases*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings7[string];](*Subsets*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings8[string];](*StringPartition*)
(*
    {0.0096, Null}
    {0.0121, Null}
    {0.00421, Null}
    {0.00573, Null}
    {0.00450, Null}
    {0.00612, Null}
*)
```

```
string = StringJoin @ ConstantArray["a", 1000];
RepeatedTiming[substrings1[string];](*ReplaceList*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings4[string];](*Table + Characters*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings5[string];](*Table + StringTake*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings6[string];](*StringCases*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings7[string];](*Subsets*)
RepeatedTiming[substrings8[string];](*StringPartition*)
(*
    {5.74, Null}
    {4.818, Null}
    {1.92, Null}
    {4.59, Null}
    {2.000, Null}
    {2.36, Null}
*)
```

Answer (score 8):

For **strings**, there is also :

```
string = "abcd";

StringCases[string, _ ~~ LetterCharacter ..., Overlaps -> All]
```

or rather (as @Kuba greatly suggested)

```
StringCases[string, __, Overlaps -> All]
```

> {abcd, abc, ab, a, bcd, bc, b, cd, c, d}

*(5 `""` are missing but that's not the point here)*

It seems almost as fast as `substrings1` according to my tests.

Comment: Even shorter: `StringCases[string, __, Overlaps -> All]` I tried this but with `Overlaps->True` :p

Comment: @Kuba Great ! ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
f[l_List] := Take[l, #] & /@ Subsets[Range[Length[l]], {1, 2}];

f[s_String] := StringJoin @@@ f[Characters[s]]
```

---

```
string = "abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcab" <> 
   "cabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabca";

a = f[string]; // Timing
```

> ```
> { 0.015600, Null}
> ```

```
Timing[b = substrings1[string];]
```

> ```
> {0.015600, Null}
> ```

```
Complement[b, a]
```

> ```
> {}
> ```

```
f @ Range @ 10
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 
>  3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
>  5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {1,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {2, 
>  3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 4, 5,
>   6, 7, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 
>  4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
>  9}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 
>  5, 6, 7, 8}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {5, 6}, {5,
>  6, 7}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {6, 
>  7}, {6, 7, 8}, {6, 7, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {7, 8}, {7, 8, 
>  9}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {8, 9}, {8, 9, 10}, {9, 10}}
> ```

Comment: Could you add timings for a larger test set? I think `0.015600` is the minimum unit of time used by `Timing`, so these could probably still be different by up to a factor of 2 or 3.

Comment: @MartinBüttner `string = StringJoin @@ RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 200];` takes `f` 0.12 second but I suppose the bigger problem is memory. I have to do something now so I can't make comparisons atm.

Comment: +1 For fast and clever solution. For strings it will be faster to write the same function with `StringTake` and `StringLength`.

Comment: @ybeltukov Thanks. That was my first approach but then I've thought that maybe OP wants a uniform approach :)