# How can one get all possible sublists of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

So if

```
list={1,2,3}
```

then output should be

```
{{},{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,2,3}}
```

or in different order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in:= Subsets[list]
out:= {{},{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{2,3},{1,2,3}}
```

Comment: That doesn't return what you asked for.  Do you want all subsets, including `{1,3}` or do you want all sublists of *contiguous* elements as your example suggests?

Comment: @Szabolcs Nice point!

Comment: And do you want the empty set or not? (Your original post suggested that you did not)

Answer (score 10):

In version 10.4 you can use

```
Subsequences[{1, 2, 3}]

(* {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: For some reason, the built-in gets quite slower for larger inputs. [Timings here.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72614/2305) (Also, I find the behaviour to return the empty list once really inconsistent, but apparently that's what the OP wants.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner, regarding the linked question RunnyKine's answer here gives four empty lists if you remove the `Union` bit.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware. :) I'll probably update my answer some time this week with additional approaches, `Catenate @` instead of `Join @@` and new timings.

Answer (score 7):

One way is this:

```
Catenate@Table[
  Take[list, {i, j}],
  {i, Length[list]}, {j, i, Length[list]}
  ]
```

Comment: [This is actually the fastest solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/72614/2305) (although I should definitely update my post to use `Catenate@` instead of `Join@@`, because the latter is a bit slower).

Answer (score 7):

One can use `SequenceCases` starting from version **10.1**:

```
Union@SequenceCases[{1, 2, 3}, {___}, Overlaps -> All]
```

> {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}

Or, if you don't want the empty list:

```
SequenceCases[{1, 2, 3}, {__}, Overlaps -> All]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2, 3}, {2}, {3}}

Answer (score 6):

```
Sort[Join[{{}}, ReplaceList[list, {___, x__, ___} :> {x}]]]
```

> {{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}}

Also:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[lst_] := With[{indices = List /@ Join @@ (Partition[Range[Length@lst], #, 1] & /@ 
       Range[Length@lst])}, Extract[lst, indices]]

f[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {a, b}, {b, c}, {c, d}, {a, b, c}, {b, c, d}, {a,
>      b, c, d}}

If you need to include `{}`:

```
Prepend[f[{a, b, c, d}], {}]
```

Comment: Ah, this is better than mine!  About the empty `{}`, notice that the OP added that to the question only after he posted his own answer with `Subsets` ... which doesn't return what he asked for even after this update to the question.